# phpbb3 how to stop same user login from different places

Tags: phpbb3

i am using phpbb3 in one of my project.

can you tell me how to stop same user login from different places?

regards

Tarique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.

you can restrict by IP so they can only login from their house, for example